# Hadoop - Upgrade from CDH4 to CDH5 MR1 - Counters

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh

**The job is completing successfully**.  I can **verify** the output of the job on HDFS.  However the 'my' counters are not even showing up on the job-details page.  It is as if they're no longer getting incremented.

Inside the map method I'm doing:
`context.getCounter(MyCounters.TOTAL).increment(1);`

`MyCounters` is an enum.

and context is `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext`

Comment: I suppose this is dup of (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33309818/317027)