# Oozie - Task Logs Do not Display

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh

Using CDH 5, when I run my oozie workflow I no longer see log-statements from my mappers (log4j, slf4j).  I even tried System.out.println - I still don't see the statements.  Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the logs are still there except you need to manually point your browser to it.  For example, clicking on a map-reduce action still opens the job log page something like (http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201510061631_2112).

However to get the result for the actual job, I need to increment the jobid to job_201510061631_2113